# DateTimePicker value is not consistent with displayed date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker, datetime-format

After spending a while trying to figure out the datetimepicker I am hardly any closer to discovering the reason for this problem. The problem is that my datetimepicker submitted form value is never consistence with the displayed date. I have the date in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`, and wish all date inputs (both written and selected through calendar) to be this value. However, the submitted date is in the format the user writes, or in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, but not consistent.

Because of this I can't really use the date submitted because it will format into the wrong date when using strtotime and so on.

**I have added datetimepicker the following way:**

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' name="birthday" ng-model="signUpInfo.birthday" placeholder="Fødselsdato" required="true">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            minDate: moment().subtract(140,"years"), 
            maxDate: moment()
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I *write*: `01.01.17` -> formats into `01/01/2017` correctly -> back-end receives `01.01.17`.

If I *write*: `01/01/2017` -> formats into `01/01/2017` correctly -> back-end receives `01/01/2017`.

If I *select*: `01/01/2017` -> formats into `01/01/2017`correctly -> back-end receives nothing.

So the displayed format is correct, but not the value being submitted, how come?

Comment: Are you overriding the submit of the form and getting data yourself somehow?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin The form is not being overriden, the only "override" is whenever the user itself types a date into the input field, but then again, datetimepicker formats this properly in display, but not in the value.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Try this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/4390/ . Import your own version of datetimepicker. Maybe you can reproduce the problem or find the answer while trying to.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin, this one isnt similar... Because you cant type in a date by hand, and have it reformatted automatically. UPDATE: Or wait... let me try this...

Comment: Can you please share some more code then?

Comment: @PhyCoMath, type 01.01.17 and press enter. It will be formatted to 01/01/2017

Comment: @DennisKoch If you try to submit the form on the website I linked, you can see what you get in return from debug-info. Sometimes it doesnt even submit. If you see what is being sent in request, you can see that whenever I select a date using the calendar it is not being sent, but when I type it is.

Comment: Is it possible that your property is named incorrectly? `format` is not a valid option... maybe you meant [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Comment: Also, the documentation says that `dateFormat` is for "*parsed and displayed dates*"... meaning, I believe, that it will be used when parsing text into dates and when displaying dates. But the underlying value is a date, not a string, and I don't think that the date picker's `dateFormat` option can be used to control the text value stored in your input. Perhaps you should use [type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) instead.

Comment: @JDB He is using the bootstrap datetimepicker not the jquery datepicker.

Comment: Ah, @dennis, thanks. Maybe the question shouldn't be tagged with jQuery, then.

Comment: It's still using jquery. But angularjs would have been a better tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger an change-Event after the datetimepicker altered the date format to update your scope variables.

```
$('#datetimepicker1').trigger('change')
```

You can bind this to the  Bootstrap Datetimepicker Event 'dp.change'

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function (ev) {
    $('#datetimepicker1').trigger('change')
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! However, why doesnt datetimepicker have this built-inn? Who would want date format for display ONLY?

Comment: Datetimepicker uses jQuery. The rest ist AngularJS. It would send the data correctly as a pure HTML form input, but not together with AngularJS.